# Reverse polarity protection + inrush current limiting with mosfets schematic

Tags: mosfet, protection, reverse-polarity, inrush-current

What do you think about this schematic? I want to put this before a DCDC 24 to 5V with maximum 1A. Any comments or suggestions? The aim of this circuit is to have a soft start with the resistor R2 in order to charge the input capacitor C1 of DCDC in a controlled way. Once the capacitor is charged, mosfet M1 is completely on, so it can bypass the resistance R2 and dissipate low power. So mosfet M1 is for soft start and M2 is for reverse polarity protection. I would use DMP4024LSS for the mosfets, with 25mOhms of Rds.
[image]
This is the real circuit with the real mosfet model
[image]
This is the simulation with -24V on-off switch
[image]

This is the Vout with 24V on-off switch
[image]

This is the controlled current in the capacitor C1
[image]

Comment: Don't use the `PMOS` model in your simulation. Select a MOSFET from the library, make sure its specs are close enough to DMP4024LSS's, and re-run your simulation.

Comment: actually the simulation is done with the spice model of the DMP4024LSS. For clarity I took the picture of the circuit with simple PMOS

Comment: It's better to put the actual circuit here to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: ok, i fixed the post

Comment: Why not use a ready-made IC for this? There are plenty of them around: Softstart + Revers-Protection. They mostly have UVLO/OVLO, ILim, and some other features as well. Some also have an EN-Pin which is quite handy in a DC/DC design.

Comment: yes, i know, but i wanted to do something of my own